# diffInHours function returns zero - Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using laravel and carbon library.
I want to get different times in hours.
but diffInHours returns zero.

```
$_startTime = $startTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
            $finishTime = $_startTime->addHours(10);
            $totalDuration = $startTime->diffInHours($finishTime);

dd($totalDuration);// 0
```

Comment: you are using same carbon object in $startTime and $finishTime use(or create) dirrent carbon object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
$startTime  = Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
$finishTime = Carbon::parse($startTime)->addHours(10); 
$totalDuration = $startTime->diffInHours($finishTime);
dd($totalDuration);
```

**Note: Parse $startime again because it modify the start time with addHours(10).**

**Explaination :**

```
$startTime  = Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
```

Here carbon object is created.

```
$finishTime = Carbon::parse($startTime)->addHours(10);
```

if i modify my `$finishTime` with below code

```
$startTime  = Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
$finishTime = $startTime->addHours(10);
```

just `dd($startTime,$finishTime)` you can see that both the `$startTime` and `$finishTime` output same data. 
Here `$startTime` create a carbon object,we need to parse `$startTime` again because its a carbon object any method append to this object will modify all it's current objects.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 1):

in your code when you do $startTime->addHours(10) and assign it to finishTime, startTime is also added with 10 hours and then that is assigned to finishTime. So in that process, both are same and the when you diff them out, the result is zero. so you need to maintain both variables separately which is shown below, hope this helps you.

```
$startTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
$finishTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-09-18 21:12:35');
$finishTime->addHours(10);
$totalDuration = $startTime->diffInHours($finishTime);
dd($totalDuration);// 10
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it?

Comment: sure, i can add.